# Meteor data context from cursor helper

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I need to display a certain data field returned from a cursor. From what I read the best way is to define a helper and then access the data into the html with the #each tags

When I use the `findOne()` inside the helper I get the right data result but only from one document ofcourse, how can I have the same result for all documents if the code for `findOne()` is like below ?(the data context in html is in a table cell ). 
The `findOne` code but only one doc field returned in html is:

```js
Template.products.helpers({
  getOffers (){
    result = OffersAggregate.findOne('offeringType-grouping').result[0].offeringType
    return result
  }
});
```

html code:

```html
 <td>{{getOffers }}<td>
```

whereas the `find()` cursor helper but with error result:

> "Exception in queued task Error: Can't call non-function:"

```js
Template.products.helpers({
  getOffers (){
    return OffersAggregate.find().fetch()
  }
});
```

```html
            <table id="table" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Country</th>                                
                        <th>Number of Offers</th>
                        <th>Offers</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>     
                    {{#each Product in Products}}   

                        <tr>
                            <td>{{Product.Name}}</td>
                            <td>{{Product.Price}}</td>
                            <td>{{Product.Country}}</td>
                            <td>{{Product.Number}}</td>
                            {{#each  offer in getOffers}}
                                {{#each result in offer.result  }}  
                                    <td>{{result.offeringType}}</td>
                                {{/each}}
                            {{/each}}   
                        </tr>
                    {{/each}}                           
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Try 'return  OffersAggregate.find().fetch()'. In relation to the #each segment, can you confirm what your 'OffersAggregate' document looks like?

Comment: @Mo A  I added a screenshot, hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your `OffersAggregate` document correctly, the following should work:

Template helper:

```
Template.products.helpers({
  getOffers (){
    return OffersAggregate.find().fetch();
  }
});
```

Register new template helper:

```
Template.registerHelper('returnValueByIndex', function (array, index){
   return array[index];
});
```

To display:

```
<table id="table" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  <th>Country</th>
  <th>Number of Offers</th>
  <th>Offers</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 {{#each Product}}
 <tr>
  <td>{{Name}}</td>
  <td>{{Price}}</td>
  <td>{{Country}}</td>
  <td>{{Number}}</td>
  <td>
  {{#with returnValueByIndex Product.[0].getOffers.[0].result @index}}
   {{this.offeringType}}
  {{/with}}
 </td>
 </tr>
 {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Comment: after some reading, testing etc I ended up with this `{{#each getOffers}}
      {{#each result }}
            <td>{{offeringType}}</td>
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}` as you can see in the updated code above. I receive the correct data (TRAM" "BUS" etc as written before) but in an extended nested cell that contains all the data retrieved from cursor into a single row of the table, whereas I need each iteration per row/cell, I tried some fixes but didn't worked out.How can I handle this if I have multiple {{#each }} annotations into a template?

Comment: The snippet I provided above iterates through 'offeringType' to print each of it's constituents individually (i.e. BUS, TRAM). Does that not work for you?

Comment: @user2829319 your code left out '{{#each offeringType}}<td>{{this}}</td>{{/each}}'

Comment: @ Mo A I need "Bus, Tram" into one cell so on purpose I left out this `{{#each offeringType}}<td>{{this}}</td>{{/each}}` the problem though now is that in each row I have all the iterations in that cell, that results into a huge cell with all the data available and not per row

Comment: It would be good if you can provide an HTML sample of what you're trying to print, then can suggest how it can be done.

Comment: I added the html for the table and how the data are displayed right now. As you can see every cell in column Offers shows all the iteration results, whereas the correct would be each single element of the 3, be shown in every cell per row.

Comment: Ok, so you want to join all 3 cells, for a given row, into a single cell? If yes, try the new code above. If not, please attach screenshot of desired output you want (using Excel for example).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187100/discussion-between-user2829319-and-mo-a).

Comment: @ Mo A thanks so much for your help! I didn't know about the global helpers and they actually worked!I could not find the solution alone for sure

Answer (score 1):

Note: give credits to Mo A's answer since this one came in first.

The context for `{{#each}}` requires an `iterable` which is either an Array or a Cursor (or a falsey value like `null` or `undefined` to skip the each-block).

Reading: http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html#Each-and-With

The function `Collection.findOne` on a collection returns a document immediately. This is a convenient shortcut for `Collection.find().limit(1).fetch()[0]` in Meteor.

For your use-case it is therefore `find()` with the right filter to be used. The error you described is not related to `find` but to the template code:

```
{{#each getOffers}}
  <!-- this will be inside a blick a reference to the current element -->
  {{#each this.result}}
    <!-- this is now refering to the result property on the current element -->
    {{#each offeringType}}<td>{{this}}</td>{{/each}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

You simple need to think the way, that inside an `each` or `with` block the `this` attribute refers to the current document. To make your `each` even easier to reason about you can use `each var in iterable`:

```
{{#each offer in getOffers}}
  {{#each result in offer.result}}
    {{#each offeringType in result}}<td>{{offeringType}}</td>{{/each}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

More to read: http://blazejs.org/guide/reusable-components.html (section "Prefer {{#each .. in}}")